# Converting to column major fashion with two dimensional array

Tags: c

I am trying to load my matrix so that consecutive numbers will go down the columns using pointer/addressing methods.  Currently my program prints the consecutive numbers across the rows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
int i,j;
int twodArray[5][5], *twodArrayptr;


int add = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {   
        twodArray[i][j]= (i*5) + j;

    }

}

twodArrayptr = &(twodArray[0][0]);

for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {
        printf("%d ", *(twodArrayptr +((i*5)+j)));


    }
    printf(" \n");

}
}
```

Comment: Well, do you want to **load** in `column order` and print in that same order, or do you want to load in `row order` and print in `column order` -- your statement is unclear. You can load//print in the same loop if you are not outputting in a different order. Regardless, both circumstances are covered in the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your point is to `load` the matrix with the opposite order, go with 4py's solution, if your point is to make use of the pointer to access the array in column order, then your solution is below.

---

You were SO CLOSE, your problem is here (you had `i` and `j` swapped). To change from row/col major ordering, you can do:

```
    printf (" %2d", *(twodArrayptr + ((j * MAX) + i)));
```

Also note the `main` is type `int` and therefore returns a value.

Putting it together, you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX 5

int main (void)
{
    int i, j, twodArray[MAX][MAX] = {{0}}, *twodArrayptr = (int *)twodArray;

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++) {
            twodArray[i][j] = (i * MAX) + j;
            printf (" %2d", twodArray[i][j]);
        }
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    putchar ('\n');

    for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < MAX; j++)
            printf (" %2d", *(twodArrayptr + ((j * MAX) + i)));
        putchar ('\n');
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$./bin/rowcol2d
  0  1  2  3  4
  5  6  7  8  9
 10 11 12 13 14
 15 16 17 18 19
 20 21 22 23 24

  0  5 10 15 20
  1  6 11 16 21
  2  7 12 17 22
  3  8 13 18 23
  4  9 14 19 24
```

Also **note:**, you do not need to use the *variadic function* `printf` to output a single *character* use `putchar` instead `:)`

Comment: It is said `load my matrix so that consecutive numbers will go down the columns` But you are loading it in the wrong way, just tweaking the output.

Comment: I misread it, in that case you get the gold star. I though the point was to change the row/col output using the pointer. Otherwise, what is the point of the pointer and single subscript if you just change `i`, `j` on initialization?

Comment: Yes! that's pretty lame. I also have no clue about the pointer.

Comment: Yes, I just edited and told them to use your answer if that was the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Change the assignment logic to `twodArray[i][j]= (j*5) + i;`

Works like a charm.

```
for(i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < 5; j++)
    {   
        twodArray[i][j]= (j*5) + i;

    }

}
```